# how to concatenate the output of vlookups in one step

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, concatenation

I'm trying to run two vlookup operations and concatenate the results in one formula as such:

```
=CONCATENATE(
VLOOKUP($A$6,'TRP'!$A$7:$D$655,2,FALSE),
"/",
VLOOKUP($A$6,'HCP'!A5:B655,2,FALSE)
)
```

The result should be  `5/6`, but instead I am getting the whole formula character for character. I know I can do this by running the vlookups in separate cells and them concatenating everything, but I'm looking to get this done in 1 step/formula and without any macros. Is it possible?

Comment: Make sure your cell that has this is formatted to general and not text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your cell that has this is formatted to general and not text. Here is how to change the format of a cell:

[image]